# how to insert DateTime column in textbox

Tags: asp.net

this is part of my code

//Instantiate the object we have to deal with
         string Name = txtName.Text;
         string Description = txtDecription.Text;
         string Topic = txtTopic.Text;
         string Sponsor = txtSponsor.Text;
         string Location = txtLocation.Text;
         System.DateTime StartDate;
            StartDate= DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
         System.DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);
         string URL = txtURL.Text;

```
     try
     {
        intResult = pBAL.Insert(Name,Description, Topic,Sponsor, Location,StartDate,EndDate,URL);
     }
```

**error**:Argumnet 6 and 7 .cannot convert from System .DateTime to 'string
Need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Your function expects string parameter you passing datatime as parameter,

Solution 1:
Change this statements

```
System.DateTime StartDate; StartDate= DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text); 
System.DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);
```

to

```
string StartDate= txtStartDate.Text; 
string EndDate = txtEndDate.Text;
```

Solution 2:
or while passing argument convert datetime object to string object

```
StartDate.ToString()
EndDate.ToString()
```

That simple,

Comment: THANKS RAMAKRISHNAN ,PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
intResult = pBAL.Insert(Name,Description, Topic,Sponsor, Location,StartDate.ToString(),EndDate.ToString(),URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your text box date format it must MM/dd/yy then it will be parse in date time format